# Groups, proving inversion to be an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

True or False? If $G$ is a group, $\psi: G\to G$ is given by $\psi(x)=x^{-1}$, then $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

False. Pick any non-Abelian group, say $G = S_3$. Then observe that $\psi$ doesn't preserve structure since for example:
$$
\psi((1,2))\psi((1,3)) = (1,2)^{-1}(1,3)^{-1} = (1,2)(1,3) = (1,3,2)
$$
while on the other hand:
$$
\psi((1,2)(1,3)) = \psi((1,3,2)) = (1,3,2)^{-1} = (1,2,3)
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Does $\psi(ab)=\psi(a)\psi(b)$?